# Is session a good choice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session, asp.net-web-api, subdomain

We are building ASP.NET MVC app that is supposed to manage sport objects reservations (tennis courts, squash courts etc).

Users are not supposed to act only in scope of one club at the moment of interaction with app.

Navigation to the app should be like:
appname.com/clubName or
clubName.appname.com

Questions:
1. What would be the best way to persist the data about selected club. We have implemented storing in session (injecting information about the club durint app opening), but we read that using session is rather deprecated solution. We are using ApiController so in order to get the session we had to hack the routing (registering custom RouteHandler). Is session mechanism applicable for this problem?

```
var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
if (session != null)
{
   service.ClubName = session[CustomSessionKeys.ClubName.ToString()].ToString();
}
```

1. Is it good idea to use subdomains for our problem?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you are only looking for the clubname, could you just pull it from the url?

Answer (score 0):

Generally a web api works differently than a normal mvc app. 
In an MVC application you would use a session cookie to make the internet act like a state machine. However, this is not what is generally done for web api's. In a web api, you provide some form of authentication (e.g. via the header authentication field). 
But within a request you ofcourse want to to keep track of the current user, or in asp.net terms, the current principal. 
We set the principle though a Delegation handler

```
HttpContext.Current.User = user;
```

If you want some more code on how this whole authentication is done, just let me know.

This was all serverside ofcourse, on the client side, you can keep any information you want in a session store. Although you might want to consider using the local storage in stead (depending on what semantics you want to give it). They both work in the same way.
You can consult [W3C webstorage specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#storage) for the complete information on both of these.

Comment: Using Sessions is bad practice for any application that uses HTTP, regardless of application framework.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Indeed, that is why i do suggest using local storage client side.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have many choices I guess!

1. Go with the route thing as you suggested, where you keep the club Id or name as part of the URL. I would go for this if I need the link to give more meaning to the user.
2. Cookie! yes, if the information is not sensitive store it in a cookie. In case this cookie is only to be accessed from server side, then don't forget to make it HttpOnly
3. Session. I agree with you, I wouldn't choose session unless the data was very sensitive and I needed to make it secure.